# how do i override template phtml file in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to override `(app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml)` this file as i have made some changes in grandtotal

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to copy the template to the rwd folder, since this is a default Magento folder. You need to override the rwd theme for that. The best way to do that is to use a theme.xml, where you can define a parent. The file should be located in `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/etc/theme.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

This makes your theme use `rwd/default` as it's parent.

Answer (score 2):

So try to copy the `rwd` folder and paste it with another name then also copy the skin folder with the same way then activate your theme.
Copy `app/design/base/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml` file to your `app/design/your_theme/namespace/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`.

So if you want to customize the `rwd` folder then you can also have a look on there https://www.flinttechnology.co.uk/customising-rwd-magento-responsive-theme/

Comment: hello Asish  it worked thanks a lot as copied to this path app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml
Isn't there is any other way as it was default rwd theme of magento and i am a newbie trying to override it from calling my layout is it possible ?

Comment: right arjen thats the point .. could you please suggest me another way is it possible to by calling own layout ?

Comment: No the temple should have to be in the your theme template folder in order to override any template

Comment: Asish am working on default theme

Comment: And this is not a good idea to copy template file in rwd caz it changes will be gone when you will update magento.. So try to copy the `rwd` folder and paste it with another name then also copy the skin folder with the same way then activate your theme

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: okay i have checked it let me try and inform you regarding thanks

Answer (score 1):

To override phtml you need to follow the following steps.

1) Login To Admin

2) Navigate to System->Configuration.

3) Select Design from general tab.

4) Under package section define you package name.

5) Under themes section define you themes name and save the configuration.

6) Create the directory with package name and theme name which you defined in the admin at this location app\design\frontend\ {package_name} \ {theme_name}.

7) Copy file grandtotal.phtml with its directry structure and paste it.
For ex if rwd is package name and custom is theme name then it will be like 
app\design\frontend\rwd\custom\template\tax\checkout\grandtotal.phtml 
and you are done.

Hope this will help you let me know if need more information.

Comment: don't  use  the default theme create your them other wise you will be in trouble if you update the magento version.